# .daファイルの代替になるものに関して※mac

Tags: php, mysql

今ドットインストールで簡易掲示板を作っています。

＜ドットインストール＞
http://dotinstall.com/lessons/bbs_php_v2/24503

動画中に「.datファイル」にデータを書き出すような処理を行いますが、
macだと.datファイル自体が開けないため代替になるものを探していますが、
何か代替になりそうなアプリケーション・ファイル形式を教えていただけませんか？

Answer (score 1):

内容はただのテキストデータですのでテキストエディタで開けます。